# JQ: Nested JSON Array transformation

Tags: jq

Since some month ago i had a little problem with a jq Transformation (j1 1.5 on Windows 10). Since them the command worked excellent: `"[{nid, title, nights, company: .operator.shortTitle, zone: .zones[0].title} 
+ (.sails[] | { sails_nid: .nid, arrival, departure } ) 
+ (.sails[].cabins[] | { cabinname: .cabinType.title, cabintype: .cabinType.kindName, cabinnid: .cabinType.nid,  catalogPrice, discountPrice, discountPercentage, currency } )]"`. Since some days ago the api deliver "bigger" json files [JSON File](https://codeshare.io/5MejJq). With the jq command i got a lot of duplicates (with the attached file i got around 3146 objects, expected objects are arround 250). I tried to Change the jq command to avoid the duplicates but had no "luck" on that. 
The json files contains a variable amount of sails (10 in these case), while each sail has a variable amount of cabins (25 in this case). Any tips how i can realize that? Regards timo

Comment: The link to "JSON File" leads to an empty page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what you're looking for:

```
[{nid, title, nights, company: .operator.shortTitle, zone: .zones[0].title} 
 + (.sails[] | ({ sails_nid: .nid, arrival, departure } +
                (.cabins[] | { cabinname: .cabinType.title,
                               cabintype: .cabinType.kindName,
                               cabinnid: .cabinType.nid,
                               catalogPrice,
                               discountPrice,
                               discountPercentage,
                               currency } ))) ]
```

Hopefully the layout will clarify the difference with your jq filter.

Comment: Hi Peak, thanks for your (fast) Input. i checked it and it works. I will compare it on the Weekend. regards timo

Comment: Work like a charm. Thanks!